# routelink not redirecting to child component

Tags: angular, angular-components, angular11, angular-routerlink

I have a child component that i want to add to my route outlet. But when i click nothing happens.

Here's my routelink

```
<li class="nav-item">
    <a [routerLink]="['/student-profile', 'student_schedule', student.id]"
    class="nav-link" [routerLinkActive]="['chosen']" data-toggle="pill">
        <i class="nav-icon fa fa-calendar-day">
        </i>
        <p class="nav-text">
            Student Schedule
        </p>
    </a>
</li>
```

Here's my studentProfileRoutingModule.

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: StudentProfileComponent
    },
    {
        path: 'address/:student_id',
        component: StudentAddressComponent
    },
    {
        path: 'contact/:student_id',
        component: StudentContactComponent
    },
    {
        path: 'guardian/:student_id',
        component: StudentGuardianComponent
    },
    {
        path: 'files/:student_id',
        component: StudentFileComponent
    },
    {
        path: 'student_record/:student_id',
        component: StudentRecordComponent
    },
    {
        path: 'student_schedule/:student_id',
        component: StudentScheduleComponent
    },
];
```

**UPDATED** 
Here's my app-routing.module

```
path: 'student-profile/:subname/:student_id',
        canActivate: [AuthGuard],
        data: {permission: 'view_student'},
        loadChildren: () => import('./features/student-profile/student-profile.module').then(m => m.StudentProfileModule)
```

Here's my studentSchedule child component.

```
ngOnInit() {}

    getStudentScheduleBySession(studentId: any, selectedSession: number): void {
        this.apiService.getStudentScheduleBySession(
            Page.getStudentSchedule, 
            studentId, 
            selectedSession
        ).subscribe(data => {
            this.schedules = data;
        },
        error => {});
    }
```

Don't know what im missing and it doesn't show any errors in console.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: please share how studentProfileRoutingModule is routed in app module! if possible a basic stackblitz with the issue!

Comment: Sorry for that bro. I have updated my post

Comment: please try changing `path: 'student-profile/:subname/:student_id',` to `path: 'student-profile',`

Comment: Sorry for getting back only now. Tried it bro and the app broke

Answer (score 0):

### WORKING EXAMPLE

[forked stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-e7hyfp)

Could you try the below changes?

Create a new dummy component(`StudentProfileWrapper`), with just `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` in the html (don't forget to add in declarations of `studentProfileModule`) and change the routing to

```
routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: StudentProfileWrapper,
        children: [
            {
                path: '',
                component: StudentProfileComponent,
            },
            {
                path: 'address/:student_id',
                component: StudentAddressComponent,
            },
            {
                path: 'contact/:student_id',
                component: StudentContactComponent,
            },
            {
                path: 'guardian/:student_id',
                component: StudentGuardianComponent,
            },
            {
                path: 'files/:student_id',
                component: StudentFileComponent,
            },
            {
                path: 'student_record/:student_id',
                component: StudentRecordComponent,
            },
            {
                path: 'student_schedule/:student_id',
                component: StudentScheduleComponent,
            },
        ],
    },
];
```

UPDATED
Here's my app-routing.module

```
path: 'student-profile',
        canActivate: [AuthGuard],
        data: {permission: 'view_student'},
        loadChildren: () => import('./features/student-profile/student-profile.module').then(m => m.StudentProfileModule)
```

Comment: Its ok bro i can test it im only using local. Tried it with studentprofile it still breaks.

Comment: @Kael Please provide more details as to what you mean by breaks?

Comment: can you replicate in stackbliz and give us link

Comment: Hello bro thanks for taking time to answer. If i change the path to student-profile it gives me this ERROR ƒ Error() { [native code] }

Comment: is it ok i just paste code? It's probably not gonna work

Comment: @Kael its ok, what version of angular?

Comment: ok bro. angular 11

Comment: @Kael try to give a stackblitz, I am out of options for a fix

Comment: yes bro just give me a moment

Comment: Sorry for the wait bro i have pasted all necessary code in stackblitz. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ftvk4s?file=src/main.ts